# SQL - Get next set of xx items

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a web API that returns the next "set" of x number of items based on the ID of the last item that was recieved. So, if my last item ID was 30, and I want 50 more, then I should get IDs 31 - 81.

If I implement an SQL query that says `SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID > 30 LIMIT 50`, am I guaranteed to get IDs 31 - 81? Or, is there a way to do that? The ID column is AUTOINCREMENT.

Also, this is SQLite, specifically. I am not sure if that matters.

Comment: Can the ID column have gaps, as by deleted records?

Comment: Yes it can. However the ID column is AUTOINCREMENT so I don't think this would be an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should also order them by id before limiting the number of results

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID > 30 
order by ID
LIMIT 50
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually in SQLite you would do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 50 OFFSET 30;
```

See http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html for documentation.